# Are there in Java thread-safe queues other than BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, collections, queue, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

From docs:

> Note that a BlockingQueue can safely be used with multiple producers and multiple consumers.

So BlockingQueue is about producers / consumers problem solving at first place, but I need just a thread safe queue without overkilling (and thus overcost) features (like producers / consumers problem solving)

(please don't suggest synchronized or immutable collections, i aware about of it)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html ?

Comment: `BlockingQueue` is an excellent choice for most applications.  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is non-blocking, but be careful, because it's non-blocking it will increase without bound, and can fill all of memory.  Use only when you are sure you can service it frequently. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: @markspace I think you meant `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

Comment: @JacobG. Yup, not enough coffee yet this morning.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @MarcelHöll, and other guys, and how about PriorityQueue? Is the PriorityBlockingQueue only option?

Comment: Are you seriously having this hard of a time reading the documentation?  Just look at the documentation for Queue and note the classes that implement it.  There's your list of options right there.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: u right, I misread ConcurrentLinkedQueue , but I felt there should be something... and BTW I think array based queues like  ArrayDeque and PriorityQueue are much more used than based on  linked nodes. So my question is not so easy, because it seems there are no any options other than BlockingQueue for array based queues...

Comment: may be my question should be formulated as: "Are there in Java thread-safe queues -based on arrays- other than BlockingQueue?"